# What value must $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ have so that $L \in \mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$} where $L := \lim_{n \to \infty} n^\beta (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis

What value must $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ have so that $L \in \mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$} where $L := \lim_{n \to \infty} n^\beta (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$ ?

---

$$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

For $n \to \infty$ we have $\sqrt{n+1} \approx \sqrt{n} \implies 1/(2\sqrt{n})$

So we have $$n^\beta \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{2}n^{\beta -0.5}$$

We have three cases: $\beta = 0.5, \beta < 0.5, \beta > 0.5$.

For $\beta = 0.5$ we get $1/2 \in \mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$} for $n \to \infty$.

For $\beta < 0.5$ we get $\frac{1}{2n^{0.5 - \beta}}$. We know $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n^{0.5 - \beta}} = 0$$ So we have $L = 0 \notin \mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$}

For $\beta > 0.5$ we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}n^{\beta - 0.5} = \infty \notin \mathbb{R}$$

---

Is this correct ? Did I forget something or made a mistake ?

Comment: looks good and the actual answer should be $\beta \leq 0.5.$ Although this looks like an exercise in a class where you are just learning convergence and sequences etc. and so you should probably make it rigorous instead of just using the $O$ notation.